# Update SQL with consecutive numbering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update a table with consecutive numbering starting with 1. The update has a where clause so only results that meet the clause will be renumbered.  Can I accomplish this efficiently without using a temp table?

Comment: Most likely this depends on the specific version of SQL you are running on, I don't think there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: What would the number be used for? Are you creating an ID? Also, I wouldn't worry about inefficiency. Given no other information, it doesn't sound like you'd be missing out on something by being grossly inefficient. Sounds like a one off operation.

Comment: I get 1.5 million listings in a 2 gb pipe delimited files each week.  I need to run a stored procedure that figures out which listings are in my clients cities, give them the client id, and number them sequentially for each client.  It must be efficient.

Comment: Now that I understand why you are numbering, The solution I proposed won't do what you need.  If multiple updates are running at the same time, you won't get consecutive numbers within that update. +1 to zombat and I have removed my answer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This probably depends on your database, but here is a solution for MySQL 5 that involves using a variable:

```
SET @a:=0;
UPDATE table SET field=@a:=@a+1 WHERE whatever='whatever' ORDER BY field2,field3
```

You should probably edit your question and indicate which database you're using however.

Edit:  I found a [solution](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/93349/sql_server_93349.html) utilizing T-SQL for SQL Server.  It's very similar to the MySQL method:

```
DECLARE @myVar int
SET @myVar = 0

UPDATE
  myTable
SET
  @myvar = myField = @myVar + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So that will increment myVar for every record the update finds.. great!  What if my numbering field is of type varchar instead of int.  Can I convert myVar to varchar as well?  Thanks again to all!

Comment: Awesome...never knew you could do that. +1

Comment: I would think that you could use varchars without problems... you can definitely have string variables. Depending on how SQL Server handles math using strings instead of integers, you might be faced with a couple of conversions throughout your SET statement, but I'm betting it wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Pretty sweet, I was hoping there is a way to do that.

Comment: MS SQL is missing the ORDER BY field2, field3

Comment: Note, using assignment operations in SQL Server queries with ORDER BY clauses has undefined behaviour. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/383641 or https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/ (this talks about strings but same issue may arise)

Comment: To anyone else who read the SQL Server code and was sceptical - it really does update all rows matching the where clause

Comment: For MS Sql you should add a query hint: OPTION (MAXDOP 1)  as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167885/update-sql-with-consecutive-numbering#comment55888771_16710393

Comment: The [solution](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/93349/sql_server_93349.html) link doesn't work anymore. Find it in the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20100505063256/http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/weighted-selection-in-t-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 41):

For Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008. ROW_NUMBER() function was added in 2005.

```
; with T as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ColumnToOrderBy) as RN
        , ColumnToHoldConsecutiveNumber from TableToUpdate
    where ...)
update T
set ColumnToHoldConsecutiveNumber = RN
```

**EDIT:** For SQL Server 2000:

```
declare @RN int
set @RN = 0 

Update T
set ColumnToHoldConsecutiveNubmer = @RN
    , @RN = @RN + 1
where ...
```

**NOTE:** When I tested the increment of @RN appeared to happen prior to setting the the column to @RN, so the above gives numbers starting at 1.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that is appears you want to create multiple sequential numbers within the table. Depending on the requirements, you may be able to do this in a single pass with SQL Server 2005/2008, by adding `partition by` to the `over` clause:

```
; with T as (select ROW_NUMBER() 
        over (partition by Client, City order by ColumnToOrderBy) as RN
     , ColumnToHoldConsecutiveNumber from TableToUpdate)
update T
set ColumnToHoldConsecutiveNumber = RN
```

Comment: Shannon your final edit has worked for me several times when I need the incremental numbers to restart for each new group and subgroup. Thank you. Your answer should be ranked higher.

Comment: This worked great for me too ... thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a new PrimaryKey column, use just this:

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Answer (score 4):

As well as using a CTE or a WITH, it is also possible to use an update with a self-join to the same table:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.columnToBeSet = b.sequence
FROM tableXxx a
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY columnX ) AS sequence, columnY, columnZ
   FROM tableXxx
   WHERE columnY = @groupId AND columnY = @lang2
) b ON b.columnY = a.columnY AND b.columnZ = a.columnZ
```

The derived table, alias b, is used to generated the sequence via the ROW_NUMBER() function together with some other columns which form a virtual primary key.
Typically, each row will require a unique sequence value.

The WHERE clause is optional and limits the update to those rows that satisfy the specified conditions.

The derived table is then joined to the same table, alias a, joining on the virtual primary key columns with the column to be updated set to the generated sequence.

Answer (score 3):

In oracle this works:

```
update myTable set rowColum = rownum
where something = something else
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm#i1006297

Answer (score 3):

To get the example by Shannon fully working I had to edit his answer:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [NameOfField]) as RowNumber, t1.ID
    FROM [ActualTableName] t1
)
UPDATE [ActualTableName]
    SET Name = 'Depersonalised Name ' + CONVERT(varchar(255), RowNumber)
FROM CTE
    WHERE CTE.Id = [ActualTableName].ID
```

as his answer was trying to update T, which in his case was the name of the Common Table Expression, and it throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE TableName
SET TableName.id = TableName.New_Id
FROM (
  SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS New_Id
  FROM TableName
  ) TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used this technique for years to populate ordinals and sequentially numbered columns. However I recently discovered an issue with it when running on SQL Server 2012. It would appear that internally the query engine is applying the update using multiple threads and the predicate portion of the UPDATE is not being handled in a thread-safe manner. To make it work again I had to reconfigure SQL Server's max degree of parallelism down to 1 core.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO

DECLARE  @id int
SET @id = -1
UPDATE dbo.mytable
SET @id = Ordinal = @id + 1
```

Without this you'll find that most sequential numbers are duplicated throughout the table.

Comment: Note, using assignment operations in SQL Server queries with ORDER BY clauses has undefined behaviour. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/383641 or https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/ (this talks about strings but same issue may arise)

Comment: Instead of changing server settings, you can use a query hint: OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

Answer (score 1):

One more way to achieve the desired result

**1. Create a sequence object** - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.mySeq
        AS BIGINT
        START WITH 1 -- up to you from what number you want to start cycling
        INCREMENT BY 1 -- up to you how it will increment
        MINVALUE 1
        CYCLE
        CACHE 100;
```

**2. Update your records**

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Col2 = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.mySeq
WHERE ....some condition...
```

**EDIT: To reset sequence to start from the 1 for the next time you use it**

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.mySeq RESTART WITH 1 -- or start with any value you need`
```

Comment: Doesn't start at 1 in the next run unless the sequence is reset. Makes it rather contrived compared to other solutions given here.

Comment: Well, I understand (also seeing the other answers, esp. the accepted one) they *always* want to start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Join to a Numbers table? It involves an extra table, but it wouldn't be temporary -- you'd keep the numbers table around as a utility.

See http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html

or

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/2547/

(the latter requires a free registration, but I find it to be a very good source of tips & techniques for MS SQL Server, and a lot is applicable to any SQL implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this single statement solution will help.  Assuming you have a column id in the table.  You need to replace table, your-integer-column and  your-where-clause-column placeholders.

```sql
UPDATE {{table-abc}} a 
SET {{your-integer-column}} = (
  SELECT COUNT(id)+1 
  FROM {{table-abc}} 
  WHERE {{your-where-clause-column}} = {{a.your-where-clause-column}} 
  AND id > a.id 
);
```

Answer (score -3):

It *is* possible, but only via some very complicated queries - basically you need a subquery that counts the number of records selected so far, and uses that as the sequence ID. I wrote something similar at one point - it worked, but it was a lot of pain.

To be honest, you'd be better off with a temporary table with an autoincrement field.