# Update database field with a variable+field_value

Tags: mysql

I am on now a big project and need to update database from MySQL, i need to update a field with some (variable value + that field value). I can do with a static value.

**Here is what i have:**

```
UPDATE table SET field_name = concat("static_value", field_name)
```

> What i need to achieve the `static_value` value should be dynamic, it
>   will start from 1 and ends with the number of rows.

How can i do this? help me!!!

Comment: Looks like a false goal. For a properly organizsed database you'd never need a static enumeration.

Comment: @AniMenon, No PHP, pure MySQL.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, basically i need a new filed in my old database and the values are like that.

Comment: Then your new database design is wrong. And the goal, for which you want to add such a field, has another, a proper solution.

Comment: Not new database, its a field only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update SQL with consecutive numbering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167885/update-sql-with-consecutive-numbering)

Comment: @AniMenon, how can i implement it in my query?? I have to add numeric value increment and a string value(that field value).

Comment: @FrayneKonok check the question I tagged.

Comment: It is not the same, I need two things, One is increment and also the field value. I don't to increment the field value only.

Comment: @AniMenon, I have a MySQL not SQL only, Can you help me with my query?

Comment: Did you even open that link? The answer says : `SET @a:=0;
UPDATE table SET field=@a:=@a+1 WHERE whatever='whatever' ORDER BY field2,field3 `

Comment: @AniMenon, I got it, little different from that one. Now i got it, thanks.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got my result. By setting a variable i can achieve what i need. Thanks to @AniMenon.

```
SET @a:=0;
UPDATE table SET `field_name` = concat(@a:=@a+1, `field_name`);
```