# Update ActiveRecord Query Record's field from 1 to n without looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any logic to update ActiveRecord Query Record's field from 1 to n.

```
@user = User.where(country: 'US')
```

Need to update above @user's field count from 1 to n.

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:

Need to update all record's - field is `count`.

AR Query will return array, need to each element in array(tuple)'s `count` field  from 1 to n

Example: AR Query Output: `[User1, User2, User3, User4, ...]`

User1's `count` field must be updated to `1`

User2's `count` field must be updated to `2` and so on.

Comment: Do you mean user has a count field on the database?

Comment: Which user field you want to update ? And change `@user` to `@users` for better name convention.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Update which field? Of a single record, or a collection of records? *Possibly* the answer you're looking for us to use `update_all`??

Comment: `User.where(country: 'US')` will not return a single user but an array of users. What do you want to update? All users in that array? To the same `n`?

Comment: Since he wrote `without looping` in the question title i assume he asking for `User.where(country: 'US', id: 1..N).update_all(whatever: value)`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database you can do it using SQL but `ActiveRecord`'s `Relation` won't support that.

Check this out: [Update SQL with consecutive numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167885/update-sql-with-consecutive-numbering)

To execute SQL you can use:

```
User.connection.execute("YOUR SQL HERE...")
```